# Error when adding foreign key - MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables in my database, user and post, I am trying to create a Foreign Key between post(author) and user(id) but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'fortifya_rasp.#sql-c1c_2151546' (errno: 150)
```

I've seen several other questions on SO and various Google searching but none of the responses have solved my issue. This is the query that I've tried

```
ALTER TABLE post ADD COLUMN author INT, ADD FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES user(id);
```

Below is the schema for post:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| timestamp | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content   | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And user:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| firstname               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fullname                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email                   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password                | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| joined_at               | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_admin                | smallint(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Update**

I've since tried this query and still receiving the same error:

```
ALTER TABLE post ADD COLUMN author INT NOT NULL, ADD INDEX (author), ADD FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES user(id);
```

And when trying to get the status after my command I get:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation
```

I then obviously tried to add privileges to see this information via

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'fortifya'@'%';
```

And I then get an error related to this:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fortifya'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When running the alter statements separately I am able to add the author column and create the index as seen below but it is still failing when attempting to create the foreign key:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| timestamp | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content   | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

[image: post Index]

Could this be an issue caused by a foreign key relationship with/from another table?

Comment: The author column needs an index (and must be the same as the user(id) column, i.e., not null)

Comment: Ahh I see, so would I run CREATE INDEX author on post(author); first then follow up with my foreign key command, adding in NOT NULL after INT?

Comment: That would work, but maybe you can also add `, add index(author)` before the `, add foreign key` and do all in one statement

Comment: Can you perform the alter statements individually to show which of them is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The author column needs an index (and must be the exactyl same type as the user(id) column, i.e., `not null`).

You can split your query into three queries (adding the column, adding an index, adding the foreign key) or try to add `, add index(author)` directly before `, ADD FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES user(id)`

More details can be gathered by issuing `SHOW ENGINE INNDODB STATUS;`

Comment: I'm getting permission errors when trying to view the engine status and then when I try to update privileges via GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'fortifya'@'%'; I get the following error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fortifya'@'localhost' (using password: YES). More errors! Grrr

Comment: After granting privileges did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`?

Comment: I get this error when trying to FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation. I'm accessing a MySQL db on a Siteground server as the main user. Could the fact that it's a shared server be causative of the permission errors?